# I can't install the A.N.T Landscape from the Addon menu

Tags: add-on, installation, error

As you can see, Blender shows the error when I try to check the box next to the A.N.T Landscape in the Addon menu.

[image]

> ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

What is the deal? I am using blender 2.79. Thank you.